# SpEL (@NumberFormat) is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-el

----SampleVO

```
@NumberFormat(pattern = "###,##0")
private int money=100000;
```

-----controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/com/spelSample.do")
public String spelSample(SampleVO sampleVO,  Model model){

    model.addAttribute("sampleVO", sampleVO);

    return "sampleResult";
}
```

-------sampleResult.jsp

```
money: <spring:eval expression="sampleVO.money"/>
```

-----expectation

```
money : 100,000
```

------but, result is

```
money : 100000
```

what is the problem?
what should i do?

Answer (score 5):

From [the `@NumberFormat` docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.html):

> Declares that a field should be formatted as a number. Supports
>   formatting by style or custom pattern string. **Can be applied to any
>   JDK java.lang.Number type**.

You are using it on a primitive field. Apparently that is not covered. Use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Edit: to be more precise, not every possible subclass of `java.lang.Number` is covered. Here is the relevant excerpt from [`NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/format/number/NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.html):

```
public NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory() {
    Set<Class<?>> rawFieldTypes = new HashSet<Class<?>>(7);
    rawFieldTypes.add(Short.class);
    rawFieldTypes.add(Integer.class);
    rawFieldTypes.add(Long.class);
    rawFieldTypes.add(Float.class);
    rawFieldTypes.add(Double.class);
    rawFieldTypes.add(BigDecimal.class);
    rawFieldTypes.add(BigInteger.class);
    this.fieldTypes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(rawFieldTypes);
}
```

This means the Atomic* classes from the concurrent api are missing, as well as all custom Number implementations from frameworks like Commons/Lang etc.

**Update:** (see comments) you also need to add `<mvc:annotation-driven>` to your context.xml.

Comment: @user909069 OK, then I guess you don't have [`mvc:annotation-driven`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) in your context.xml